# Is this sentence grammatically correct? (in less than ... since)

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

> The man died in less than a month since the start of his fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's incorrect. It should be something like this:

> The man **died less than a month from** the start of his fast.

You can say:

> It's been less than a month since he began his fast, but he's died.
>   He died less than a month from the beginning of his fast.
>   In less than a month from the beginning of his fast, he died.
>   Since [*time reference*, not synonymous with *because*] he began his fast, he's had heart trouble, stomach problems, and psychological traumas.

*[Since](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/since)* is a difficult word for EFL students to use properly. This link gives some good examples of proper usage.

Comment: +1, excellent answer; the alternative forms you wrote are exemplary.

Comment: You should explain that "since" is used with an ongoing action which began at the time named while "from" is used for a short completed action which began after the delay named.